# How do I set a center container to stay responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have three containers (`div`), the third div has a set width but I need the other two to be responsive. Current html setup:

```
<div id="page-type">
        <div id="type-container">
            <div>
                <p id="type-title">Events</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="type-options">

        </div>
        <div id="type-back">
            <a href="#" id="back">Back to Explore</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Current css:

```
#page-type {
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: #D2D3D5;
height: 60px;
}
#type-container {
float: left;
width: auto;
}
#type-options {
height: 60px;
width: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
#type-back {
border-left: 1px #BDBEC1 solid;
float: right;
width: 160px;
}
```

I can get `type-container` and `type-options` to be on the same line and responsive but I can't keep `type-back` on the same line.

visual example:
[image]

----- EDIT -----
To clarify more:

- `type-container` adjusts to fit it's content
- `type-back` is a set width
- `type-option` fills in the space between `type-container` and `type-back` regardless of content

`type-container`and `type-options`  fill up the whole row pushing `type-back` to the next line. I need `type-back` to stay to the right of the line while the other two are responsive.

Comment: The "third div" is a SPAN. First change this - because SPAN is an inline element and DIV is a block element. Unless you are talking about some other divs ? Please note their names, to be as clear with the problem as possible

Comment: What do you want exactly, first you said "third div has a set width but I need the other two to be responsive" then you said "I can't keep type-back on the same line". Aren't these two lines reffering to the same `<div>` or in your case same `<span>` and isn't it obvious that to keep it on the same line you will have to make it responsive also...

Comment: Your span is a inline element which will maintain some of the spacing around it. you should start it right after the closing of the div thats next to it or you will get a ~1 px space in the markup which could be pushing enough to drop the span into another row.

Comment: @wick3d - forgot to change the span back to a div.

Comment: basically I have three containers: the first two need to be responsive, the last one needs to have a set width.

Comment: I've updated my question, changing the span to a div. But my issue remains. The left div plus the center div is taking up the whole row and pushes the third div down.

Comment: Added more info for clarification

Answer (score 4):

Put a wrapper around your first two columns and then you can use CSS3's `calc()`.

```
#wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 161px); /* extra px for 1px border */
    float: left;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/9QPvD/)

IE8 Workaround - Use border-box:

```
#wrapper {
    margin-right: -161px;
    padding-right: 161px;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[IE8 Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9QPvD/2/)

Comment: This might work. IE8 doesn't support it but I might be able to justify a fallback

Answer (score 2):

In CSS3 you can use `calc(X% - 160px)` to reduce the width of a percentage based container by a number of pixels.

A quick example could be: http://jsfiddle.net/e3vC4/

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a need to use `calc` for this, even though its a nice feature to have (+1) — sadly its support is still patchy in places and despite much research it's still difficult to say exactly which browser versions will work as expected *(fine if you assume all modern browser users auto-upgrade however)*.

Depending on what your prerequisites are, you have two other options that I'm aware of:

### 1. Position absolute the last column

This is a simple solution, however something to be wary of is that certain older mobile devices may treat position absolute in odd ways.

In order to get this to work, all you need to do is place `position: relative` on your container, and `position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;` on your third column... and to keep the centering of your central column correct, add `margin-right: 161px`.

[Pos. Abs. example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XTagH/1/)

**CSS** ~ markup is as per your example

```
#page-type {
  display: block;
  position: relative; /* added */
  width: 100%;
  background: #D2D3D5;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#type-container {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#type-options {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 161px; /* added */
}

#type-back {
  display: block;
  position: absolute; /* added */
  right: 0; /* added */
  top: 0; /* added */
  border-left: 1px #BDBEC1 solid;
  width: 160px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

### 2. Float right, and/or left, before sibling without hasLayout / shrinkwrap

This works on the basis that a floated element takes up space in the document, and a block element, by default, auto-expands to fill the remaining area that it can — as long as it hasn't been forced to rigidly define its edges with the likes of float, overflow or other *hasLayout* or *shrinkwrap* tricks.

This option is only open to you if you can re-arrange your DOM ordering i.e. place `#type-back` before `#type-options`. This won't affect the visual order, but it makes a big difference to how the layout is calculated, and is one of the reasons why you were encountering problems with your attempts. You need to have the floated elements in place before leaving the other elements to calculate their dimensions.

[Float example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4W3B/1/)

> **NOTE:** Changing the order of DOM elements can be of benefit, but it can also be a hindrance; it all depends on what the markup is, and who will be viewing it. For example, sometimes having actionable links higher up the DOM can be useful to tabbing and screen-reader users, but the opposite can also be true depending on the context.

**MARKUP** ~ note the rearranged DOM order

```
<div id="page-type">
  <div id="type-container">
    <p id="type-title">Events</p>
  </div>
  <div id="type-back">
    <p><a href="#" id="back">Back to Explore</a></p>
  </div>
  <div id="type-options">
    <p>Options</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#page-type {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #D2D3D5;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#type-container {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#type-options {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#type-back {
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px #BDBEC1 solid;
  width: 160px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

> **NOTE:** It should be stated this version does break on to the next line when "responsed" down to a very minimal size. However, I tend to prefer to design items to disappear when space is tight, and this method lends well to that thinking.

### Summary

These are just two other possible options. If you are developing for a progressive client, or yourself, then I personally would stick with the `calc` method. It's easier to work out what is going on, and far easier for a future developer to change.

However, <del>sometimes</del> <del>*often* *frequently*</del> **all the blasted time** clients want to support the widest range of devices possible (without investing the extra time and money that would be required), and in this instance you are better off with an alternative method (one that isn't going to randomly break on a manager's less than contemporary laptop, running IE 7.5? or 8.33333??? or even Netscape 4.7¿).

Unless of course, you have any leeway to fight for using the more progressive approach, which does seem to be getting easier of late.

Answer (score 0):

I sat down with the designer for more clarification and to discuss alternate solutions. I'm making the third did responsive as well allowing me to use two containers: one holds `page-type` and `type-options` set to x% and another holds `type-back` set to y%. Doing this allows me to keep all elements responsive.